# KIndly advise if Class 1 BLE 4.0 -20dBm input or/and output sensitivity?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

i am building a class 1 BLE 4.0 100m but not sure if the -20dBm specfication is an output or receiving standard? Please any one with this information. Regards!

Comment: -20 dBm would be absurdly insensitive, so this has to be a transmit level of some sort... And quite possibly a typo.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Bluetooth specification, a class 1 device has a transmit power of +20dBm and a range of up to 100 m, a class 2 device has a transmit power of 4 dBm and a range up to 10 m, while a class 3 device has a transmit power of 0 dBm and a range up to 1 m. Where is a value of -20 dBm specified?

Comment: Barry is 100% correct.  Furthermore, the Bluetooth Spec requires a minimum of -70dBm receiver sensitivity. Modern devices have around -90dBm of sensitivity.